# Documenting Unit Test results in VS 2013

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to automatically document the test result in visual studio 2013. I mean generating text files which include all the expected results and actual results as well the tested components etc.

I could copy the result for individual test methods manually but the problem is that it only included the final test result (passed, failed), I have to document the full unit test and in that case I have to manually add the name of the tested component as well the actual result and expected result so doing this manually takes a lot of time, so I asked this question to make sure if there's really no anyway to do this in visual studio automatically.

Comment: Are you using as Build system like TeamCity, TeamBuild etc...

Comment: can you be more specific about what you want to document?